# Sorting a vector in C++ by accessing a private member

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, private-members

I'm working on a project and I have to sort a vector, but I'm facing some difficulties.

```
class CService {
    private:
        string m_strSeller;
    public:
        // Other stuff.
};

class CAnalizeTime : public CService {
    private:
        void sortSellerVector () {
            vector<CService>m_vData;
            m_vData.push_back(m_strSeller);
            sort(m_vData.begin(), m_vData.end());
        }
};
```

I'm getting 2 errors on my `void sortSellerVector()` function:

1. Cannot access private member declared in class 'CService'
2. Cannot convert from 'class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >' to 'const class CService'

My questions are:

1. How do you access a private member from another class?
2. What exactly does the second error mean? I don't understand it.

Comment: Do you really want to use inheritance here? Also, you have a vector of `CService`s here, yet you're trying to `push_back` a `string`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Analize?  Sounds painful...

Comment: I removed the inheritance but I still can't access the private member. I have to create a vector out of CService and sort it by sellers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to sort a `vector<CService>`, the easiest way is to just give `CService` an `operator<` overload that `std::sort` can use to sort the elements. Of course, this `operator<` overload will have access to `m_strSeller` if it is a member function:

```
class CService {
  private:
    string m_strSeller;
  public:
    bool operator<(const CService& other) const
    {
      return m_strSeller < other.m_strSeller;
    }
    /////..... (other stuff)
};
```

Then you can just do:

```
vector<CService> vData;
// Push some CServices into the vector
sort(vData.begin(), vData.end());
```

An alternative method is to have a comparison function that you give to `std::sort` to use. You can make it a friend of `CService` so that it can access the private member:

```
class CService {
  private:
    string m_strSeller;
  public:
    friend bool compare(const CService&, const CService&);
    /////..... (other stuff)
};

bool compare(const CService& a, const CService& b)
{
  return a.m_strSeller < b.m_strSeller;
}
```

Which you then use like so:

```
vector<CService> vData;
// Push some CServices into the vector
sort(vData.begin(), vData.end(), compare);
```

Comment: do I change the bottom class or not, cause if I leave it like this i get "undeclared identifier" error

Comment: @user2374907 I can't see any reason you need the `CAnalizeTime` class just for the `sortSellerVector` function. Nonetheless, you can keep it, just there's no reason for it to inherit and you should update the function body to contain what I gave above. If this doesn't work, tell me your error.

Comment: well my project says that I have to create this class and inside it to sort the vector by sellers. And as I said if I leave it like this: class CAnalizeTime {
 private:
  void sortSellerVector () {
   
   vector<CService>m_vData;
   m_vData.push_back(m_strSeller);
   sort(m_vData.begin(),m_vData.end());

  }
};

I get the error I mentioned

Comment: @user2374907 You're trying to push `m_strSeller` into a vector of `CService`s. You can't do that. You need to push `CService` objects into it. `CAnalizeTime` doesn't need to know anything about `m_strSeller`, it just needs to put `CService` objects in the vector and sort it.

Comment: can you please write down this line of code cause I really have no idea what exactly should I write

Comment: @user2374907 Exactly what I wrote in the question above. The 2nd or 4th code blocks depending on which solution you chose. To add `CService` objects to the vector, do something like `CService service(constructor, args, here); vData.push_back(service);`.

Comment: is this what im suppose to write 
vector<CService>m_vData;
CService service(string m_strSeller);
m_vData.push_back(service);
sort(m_vData.begin(),m_vData.end(),compare);

Comment: @user2374907 You're constructing a `CService` object incorrectly. It should be something like `CService service("Blah blah");`.

Comment: why this blah blah cant be my variable in this case m_strSeller

Comment: @user2374907 That just doesn't make sense. `m_strSeller` is a member of `CService`. You can't pass it to `CService`'s constructor. Get a good C++ book and read about classes.